# How to resolve issue in getting connected to SQL Azure Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-connection, azure-sql-database

I configured the SQLAzure database. I configured the firewall for my IP and when am trying to connect to that database from my local using SQL Server Management studio, getting below error

> TITLE: Connect to Server Cannot connect to XXXXX.database.windows.net.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476
>
> The network path was not found

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: This question looks like it has been abandoned, with no clear instructions to reproduce the behaviour, so I am closing it as "no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things:

1. Ensure SQLAzure database name is correct (the error that you posted translates to name doesn't even exist)
2. Try adding port number at end of the connection

   ```
   XXXXX.database.windows.net,1433
   ```

If the issue still persists, try pinging the SQLAzure from your local machine.

Comment: yes server is correct 
and 
i tried using the server name as below

XXXX.database.windows.net:1433   , but still not able to connect and the same error is comming

Answer (score 0):

Please also check network protocol when you connect to Azure database via SSMS. It seems you are using named pipes and TCP/IP is excepted.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bravo are you able to browse the instance via Visual Studio if you have it installed?

Can you also confirm that you are not behind a corp firewall that blocks 1433 outbound?

Really minor thing but the title of the error has a trailing "." which if that is the machine name you are trying to connect to won't work - it may just be appended by the error message.